# How can I export images from xml feed?

Tags: xml, export, feed

i need to locally download all images from xml feed.
There are about 8000 images.

All images that i need are all JPGs and in this syntax:

```
<IMGURL>
<![CDATA[ https://example.com/image.jpg ]]>
</IMGURL>
```

Can somebody help me with this? Thank you ;)

Comment: What do you want to do with these images? Copy them to local filestore?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use Saxon then the following XQuery would do the job:

```
for $url in //IMGURL ! normalize-space()
let $filename := tokenize($url, '/')[last()]
return file:write-binary($filename, saxon:read-binary-resource($url))
```

Comment: I have no idea how to use it

Comment: Well, I'm not going to post a copy of the documentation here. If you get stuck, ask another question explaining your difficulties.